# Populate ItemsControl from a Collection which is incomplete

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to create a PDF previewer in WPF and want to display pages in an `ItemsControl` bound to an `ObservableCollection` of rendered pages (each page is a `BitmapSource` instance). The `ItemsControl` is also inside a `ScrollViewer`. Now, I don't want to render all the pages at once because there can be a hundred of them and they will eat up memory really fast. I want to render only the ones which are visible in the app window. But, at the same time I want the `ItemsControl` to be as big as the number of all the pages in the PDF document so that the `ScrollViewer`'s scrollbar is adequately small and shows how much more there is to scroll.

So the question is, how to make the `ItemsControl` as big as the number of all the pages but NOT make the `ObservableCollection` have all the pages?

I also considered replacing the `ItemsControl` with a `Grid` and add some dummy items with the `Height` set to the height of the page and then replace it with the actual page when it's visible to user but that seems like a lot of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having an `ObservableCollection<BitmapSource>` (which you seemingly have) you should have an `ObservableCollection<Page>`, where `Page` is a class with a BitmapSource property that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, e.g.

```
public class Page : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private BitmapSource image;

    public BitmapSource Image
    {
        get { return image; }
        set
        {
            image = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Image)));
        }
    }
}
```

You could now create as many `Page` instances as there are pages in your document and put them into the ObservableCollection. Only when a Page is actually loaded, you would assign its `Image` property, which would trigger a Binding like this in the ItemTemplate:

```
<ItemsSource.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
    <DataTemplate>
</ItemsSource.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Can I create Width and Height in the Page class to make sure the ItemsControl reserves enough screen space for each page (so that the ScrollViewer's scrollbar has proper size)?

Comment: You would probably set a fixed size of the Image control. Otherwise you could of course bind its Width and Height to appropriate properties of the Page class.

Comment: so something like
`<Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width="{Binding Path=Width}" Height="{Binding Path=Height}" />` ?

Comment: Sure, why don't you just try it?